# Printer works for a while, then stops responding. Reinstalling fixes it for a while, then "Printer not responding" again

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I'm using an HP Laserjet Pro, and in CUPS picking this driver:

HP LaserJet Pro MFP M227-M231 Postscript (recommended) (grayscale, 2-sided printing)

This works, the printer responds and prints a test page. Printing and scanning work fine after that.

A while later, maybe a few days, the printer stops responding.  Print jobs hang, says "Printer not responding" although the printer is on, and says on its front panel display it is on such and such local IP address.  Printer is connected through ethernet cable to a router sitting next to the computer.

Deleting the printer through CUPS and reinstalling all of the same drivers fixes the problem. For a while.  How can I prevent it in the first place?

I have tried waking up the printer on the front panel display, power cycling the printer, pause and resume printer in CUPS, print test page (always hangs when the problem is occurring), modify printer (re-install the same driver), but the only step that fixes the problem in CUPS is deleting the printer and reinstalling the same driver I was using previously.  "Find New Printers" always finds the printer, even when it is "not responding".

I can power off the printer through the front panel power button, power it back up, and if it was working previously it still works.  If it was not responding previously it still does not respond.

If your suggestion includes any troubleshooting steps while the problem is occurring, my apologies but it may be several days before the problem re-emerges, so this may be a slow thread!

[EDIT] Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, printer is an HP Laserjet MFP M227fdn.

Comment: Hello. I do not see a version of Ubuntu in this question.

Comment: Sorry, see edit on =original post

Comment: Is this connected via USB? If you look at the DEVICE URI properties of the defined printer in **Additional Printer Settings**, what URI string does it show?

Comment: Look at the logs with `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u cups`. Read `man journalctl`.